# Why can I I break out of the while loop?

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to write a python function that generates random n-mers (each character can be one of (ACGT) in the end. But the while loop seems to go on forever. Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
def add_base(x):

    random_seqs = []
    for char in "ACGT":
        y = x + char
        random_seqs.append(y)
    return random_seqs


def random_n_mer(n):

    print("Random " + str(n) + " mers")
    i = 1

    random_mers_next = []
    random_mers = add_base("")

    while i < n:

        for base in random_mers:
            print(base)
            random_mers_next.extend(add_base(base))
            print(random_mers)
            print(random_mers_next)
        random_mers = random_mers_next
        i = i+1

random_n_mer(3)
```

Comment: It will be easier to figure out what's wrong here if you could reformat the code to show the actual indentation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will go on a limb here and guess:

you're missing

`random_mers_next = []`

So try this:

```
while i < n:

    for base in random_mers:
        print(base)
        random_mers_next.extend(add_base(base))
        print(random_mers)
        print(random_mers_next)
    random_mers = random_mers_next
    random_mers_next = []
    i = i+1
```

Without it you're rapidly extending random_mers - on every `i` iteration you process previously produced elements twice, which adds exponential growth on top of 4 times growth by the algorithm itself.

Comment: This worked brilliantly. Thanks, Radostlaw.  But I still have the same question I post above to Alan....

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your while loop goes on forever is that you set your `random_mers` variable to `random_mers_next`. Inside your for loop for the `random_n_mer(n)` function, you extend `random_mers_next` making the list longer. After, you say that `random_mers` is equal to that list. Since the for loop is iterating through each value in the `random_mers` list, and you keep adding to that list, it will never end.

Comment: Thank Alan. I would have thought within the while loop, each iteration runs all the steps through the last step (which is i += 1) before it starts the next iteration (beginning with for-loop). The "random_mers = random_mers_next" is the second step outside the for-loop.  But it looks like it automatically feedbacks the value to the for-loop before executing the i+=1?

Comment: Yup, that is correct. It will feed the value into the for loop every time which causes it to never end.